# Update the about text of a message extension bot

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

How to update the text which appears on the hover of the message extension bot in Microsoft Teams using bot framework v3.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part you can change directly is the description in the top. The "permissions" section you've highlighted you can't change explicitly, as they're based on what your Teams app contains. For instance, if you app contains a bot, then by definition it will be able to "receive messages and data that I provide to it". Things like your bot scope will also influence this - what I mean is if you bot is ONLY a personal, 1-1 bot, then you wouldn't have "access this team's information", because it doesn't apply to a 1-1 bot. In contrast, if you've selected that your app contains a bot, and the bot can be used in a Team channel, then it would need that permission.

Also relevant are the other permissions you explicitly request for your app. In App Studio, these would be on the "Domains and permissions page" under "Device permissions".